# python: how to evaluate items in a list

Tags: python, variables

This is probably pretty simple, but I have a list with strings that also correspond to variable names:

```
listname = ['name1', 'name2," ... ]

name1 = "somestring"
name2 = "some other string"
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
for variable in listname:
    [perform some operation on the string associated with the variables 
    named in listname, i.e. "somestring" and then "some other string," etc.]
```

Is there an easy way to force evaluation of the strings in `listname` as variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to do this. Use a dictionary:

```
d = {'name1':name1, 'name2':name2}

for myvar in listname:
    myvar = d.get(myvar)
    do_stuff(myvar)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are times when this can be useful

```
for variable in listname:
    target = vars().get(variable)
```

Usually it's better to just have a list of the objects, or use a separate namespace as @Haidro suggests

Answer (score 1):

```
For item in string_list:
   # possibly do some string manipulation such as
   # item = item + '+= 1'
   eval(item)
   # or even exec(item)
```

Comment: [eval is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: @Haidro In this case, where the OP would be `eval`ing hard coded variable names, is `eval` really that dangerous?  Surely if `eval` will never accept user input it can't be more dangerous than the code itself, or am I missing something?

Comment: @SethMMorton If he defined the list himself, he could have done [name1, name2, etc] (not strings). The list could be from somewhere else, but eh :p

Comment: @Haidro Agreed... I'm not saying that `eval` is the best method in this case, but I'm suggesting that there are probably cases where including `eval` in your code won't jeopardize the safety of innocent children :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the python map function:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

You can define a function, which does that switch, and pass the function and list into the in-built map function.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just put the objects in the list.

```
name1 = "some string"
name2 = "some other string"

listname =[name1, name2]

for s in listname:
    do something with s
```